# Allow access to specific URLs only via .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am using a Wordpress website. Recently there has been URL injection on my site that created thousands of URL's and that got indexed on Google. Genuine URL's on my website are 31 only. I need help with .htaccess file (or probably any other way) where as when user access any page other than those valid 31 pages, they either get some error or get redirected to Home Page. There is no fixed pattern of injected URL's. I searched entire Web but could not find an answer. If we can achieve this, we can prevent our site from being blacklisted from Google.

Comment: Hope you have gone through steps stated here: https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Comment: Yes, I had gone through that link. But what I want is some kind of control via .htaccess or some other medium where as when user access any page other than those valid 31 pages, they either get some error or get redirected to Home Page. Need expert advise here... May be someone with .htaccess knowledge can help.